# Lightning component ui:inputDate not working properly in Salesforce1

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app

I have a problem with a ui:inputDate field. I have a lightning app where I create dynamically a component. The created component is a form that contains an ui:inputDate field. On creation I set this date field to a date. While in salesforce the created component is rendered correctly and the set date is visible, when I run the app in salesforce1 the initial set date is not visible.

Anyone any thoughts on that? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you confirm if it's a lightning app?  Or a component embedded on record detail page?

Comment: Hi Sumuga, I confirm it is a lightning app.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had a format 'dd-mmm-yyy' that did not work for all devices. Format 'YYYY-MM-DD' makes the date shown in all devices not in same format but at least it is shown. Thanks for any time spent for my question.